# Are BPMN sequenceFlow allowed to reference specific activities within another process/subprocess?

Tags: bpmn

I am modeling a complex process using BPMN 2.0
I have split the process into multiple global processes which can reference one another through call activity.

However, in one or two special cases, I would like to actually call directly into the middle of one of the other processes.  I do not want to have to create an entirely duplicate [sub]process with just the first couple nodes missing and would also prefer not to split those couple nodes into their own little process.

I don't think common BPMN 2.0 tools support this, but is it explicitly disallowed by the spec?  For instance, I read through http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.2/PDF and I don't see anywhere that it claims that a sequenceFlow's targetRef must be within the same FlowElementsContainer.  Maybe it is just implied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to create several "none" start events in the global process and then reference the correct one via the targetRef attribute of a sequence flow incoming to the call activity. The spec says on p. 239:

> "If the Process is used as a global Process (a callable Process that
>   can be invoked from Call Activities of other Processes) and there are
>   multiple None Start Events, then when flow is transferred from the
>   parent Process to the global Process, only one of the global Process’s
>   Start Events will be triggered. The targetRef attribute of a Sequence
>   Flow incoming to the Call Activity object can be extended to identify
>   the appropriate Start Event."

Comment: Thank you, I think its just what I need!  But now comes the next question...HOW should targetRef be extended to identify the appropriate Start Event?!  Is there any precedence on what such an extension might look like?

Comment: Opened my follow-up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725477/how-to-specify-which-start-event-should-be-called-from-a-bpmn-callactivity